# Setting up a Workforce Field - Connecting Workforce and Collector

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-collector, workforce

I am working on connecting Workforce Developer and Collector and I am trying to set up a specific field as a collector field. There are 3 fields that I can choose from, but none of them are what I am looking for. Are their stipulations to choosing a collector field?

[image]

UPDATE:
I was able to get the field that I was interested in. I just had to make sure that the field was a text field. However, when I go to create a work order the work order ID does not populate even though the ID has been set up to correspond with the feature class field. Is there some reason why my workforce ID is not autopopulating?

Answer (score 0):

This dialogue box is actually used to auto-populate a field in Collector, not Workforce.